# Remove column by name?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

how can I delete columns from a file by specifying column name by using shell scripting commands?

Input file:
A B C D
1 2 3 4

And if i specify A, I want output to be:
B C D
2 3 4

I've tried awk, sed and cut but I am not sure how to implement the name part. I know that I can write names of the other columns with awk and print them only thus removing the others not specified, but I want to remove the specified columns and not to use this workaround. Thanks!

Comment: please share a sample of the input file, and the expected output.

Comment: @akathimi I've added this to the question

Comment: `
#!/bin/bash

# Store the column name to be removed in a variable
column_name="$1"

# Get the column number to be removed
column_number=$(head -n1 input.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -n "$column_name" | cut -d: -f1)

# Use awk to remove the specified column from the file
awk -v col="$column_number" '{ for (i=1; i<col; i++) printf("%s ",$i); for (i=col+1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%s ",$i); printf("\n"); }' input.txt > temp.txt

# Overwrite the original file with the modified data
mv temp.txt input.txt
`